# http timeout https works - Apache ssl redirect doesn't work

Tags: apache-2.4, https, redirect

Asking myself this question because it took me very long to figure out and I hope I can help others, to be faster.

On my server https://example.com worked fine and I set up a redirect to make sure it would never be viewed as http://example.com  -

Yet no redirect seemed to work. I tried numerous variations of Apache config.

Browsers timed out on http - I tried wget to make sure it wasn't cookies or something.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out port 80 was blocked by ufw.
I didn't think I needed it. This was the output of

```
ufw status
```

> Status: active
> To                         Action      From
>
> 22                         ALLOW       Anywhere                   443
> ALLOW       Anywhere                   22 (v6)
> ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)              443 (v6)
> ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)

```
ufw allow 80
```

fixed it.